# Find the norm of a linear functional on a bounded close interval

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider $C[0,1]$ and let $g \in C[0,1]$. Define a linear functional $T$ on $C[0,1]$ by
$$T(f) = \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx.$$
Show that $||T||=\int_0^1 |g(x)|dx$, where $||g|| = \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|g(x)|$.
It is easy to show that $||T|| \le \int_0^1 |g(x)|dx$, but I am stuck in the opposite side. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is defined as $f(x)=\text{sgn}(g(x))$, then we have that
$$\int_0^1 fg = \lVert g \rVert_1$$
And $\lVert f \rVert = 1$, but $f$ is not continuous. But you can make $f_n$ a continuous approximation of $f$ and get that $\lVert Tf_n \rVert$ can be made arbitrary close to $\lVert g \rVert_1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. But is it possible to show it without invoking Lusin's Theorem?

Comment: @Charles I think you can do an $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof. You need to "fix" $f$ at the points where $g=0$. You can assume that this set is not dense is $[0,1]$, because that would mean that $g=0$ on $[0,1]$. If you have finitely many zeroes, you can "rotate the vertical line" connecting the $1$ and $-1$ values, which will make it continuous. But if there are infinitely many zeroes, I don't know what could you do, because you can't just simply do the same thing.

Comment: @Charles I think you could use the Weierstraß theorem somehow. I'll think about it.